# How to display Bus configuration on MassTransist

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with Rabbit MQ v5.1.4 on a netcore console app.

Suppose I have the following:

```
public MassTransitConfigurator()
{
    bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
    {
        var host = sbc.Host(Settings.Rabbit.Uri, h =>
        {
            h.Username(Settings.Rabbit.User);
            h.Password(Settings.Rabbit.Pass);
        });

        sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, Settings.Rabbit.Queue, e =>
        {
            e.Consumer<FooConsumer>();
            e.Consumer<BarConsumer>();
        });

        sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, Settings.Rabbit.FaultQueue, e =>
        {
            e.Consumer<FooFaultConsumer>();
            e.Consumer<BarFaultConsumer>();
        });
    });
}
```

When I call a method that has access to the `bus` instance I would like to log the following:

```
public void StartListening()
{
    bus.Start();
    // What to do here so that we get something like:
    Console.WriteLine($"Listening on: {Settings.Rabbit.Uri}");
    Console.WriteLine($"      Queues: ");
    Console.WriteLine($"           - {Settings.Rabbit.Queue}");
    Console.WriteLine($"           - {Settings.Rabbit.FaultQueue}");
    Console.WriteLine($"      Event Types: ");
    Console.WriteLine($"           - {Foo}");
    Console.WriteLine($"           - {Bar}");
}
```

but getting the data from the `bus` instead of manually codding it in the logs.

I've looked at the official [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/) but I don't see anything like this.

---

**Notes:**

- The `Console.WriteLine` would be a logger class.
- The `Settings` class would be values read from configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the bus configuration as an object graph, which you can convert to JSON using JSON.NET:

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/troubleshooting/show-config.html